# Error while decrypting file via AES in c#

Tags: c#, exception, encryption

I am building a application that can encrypt and decrypt files, in c#. The encryption seems like its working (I think its working) however the decryption gives me the exception "The input data is not a complete block." I have tried almost everything I could find online so I thought I should come here. Here is the decryption code:

```
static void decryptAES (/*byte[] buffer,*/string filePath,byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        AES.Key = key;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        AES.KeySize = 128;
        AES.IV = IV;

        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform crypt = AES.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream))
                    {
                        //breaks here                      
                        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);

                        File.Move(filePath, filePath.Replace(".encrypted", ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It breaks on the line with the comment //breaks here by the way.
Thanks.

Here is the encrypt function

```
  static void encryptAES(byte[] filesBytes,string 
 filePath,AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
    {
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform crypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {

                using (CryptoStream csStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    csStream.Write(filesBytes, 0, filesBytes.Length);



                }
                try { File.Move(filePath, filePath + ".encrypted"); }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the key generation:

```
 static AesCryptoServiceProvider generateAES()
     {
         AesCryptoServiceProvider a = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
         a.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         a.BlockSize =128;
        a.KeySize = 128;
        a.GenerateIV();
            a.GenerateKey();
         return a;

     }
```

Here is how I stored the IV and AES Key:

```
private static void dumpKeys(AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
    {
       foreach (byte b in aes.Key)
        {
            Console.Write(b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (byte b in aes.IV)
        {
            Console.Write(b);
        }
        byte[] encryptedKey = encryptRSA(aes.Key);
        byte[] encryptedIV = encryptRSA(aes.IV);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Keys");
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Keys\0000000000000.Key", encryptedKey);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Keys\1111111111111.IV", encryptedIV);
    }
```

And here is how I retrieve the key and iv data:

```
byte[] AESKey = decrypt(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Keys\0000000000000.Key");

        byte[] AESIV = decrypt(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Keys\1111111111111.IV");


static byte[] decrypt(string path)
    {

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {             
            RSA.FromXmlString(Properties.Resources.privateKey);
            byte[] unencrypted = RSA.Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(path), true);             
            foreach (byte b in unencrypted)
            {
                Console.Write(b);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();            
            return unencrypted;
        }
    }
```

Btw I store a public RSA key in my resources file and I use that to decrypt the key. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same `Key` and the same `IV` for both encrypting and decrypting? Are you flushing the stream when encrypting? You should also specifiy a `CipherMode`. Don't know that the default one is... Could you add your encryption function to your post?

Comment: Ill post the encryption and key generation. I am using the same Key and IV

Comment: have you checked that the encrypted and the decrypted key/iv are the same? Try hard-coding the key/IV and test again...

Comment: @Michael I had a Console.Writeline for the key and IV and they outputted same so I think thats not the issure. I will try out your code that you posted.

Comment: @Michael I tried hardcoding the key as a new byte[16] so 0000000000000000 and it still threw the "input data is not a complete block". Im starting to suspect that something is happening with the padding because that is supposed to fix the input data so it fits in the block.

Comment: have you tested my code with the file you want to encrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, so good. Do you extract the generated `Key` and `IV`? I modified your decryption function to an encryption function...

```
public static void Main()
{
    var f = @"q:\test.txt";

    AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;
    AES.KeySize = 128;

    AES.GenerateKey();
    AES.GenerateIV();

    var key = AES.Key;
    var iv = AES.IV;

    encryptAES(AES, f, key, iv);
    decryptAES(AES, f + ".encrypted", key, iv);
}
static void encryptAES(SymmetricAlgorithm algo, string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
        using (FileStream fin = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(filePath + ".encrypted", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform crypt = algo.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fout, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        fin.CopyTo(crStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
static void decryptAES(SymmetricAlgorithm algo, string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform crypt = algo.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream))
                    {                  
                        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        File.WriteAllText(filePath.Replace(".encrypted", ".restored"), data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ill edit my post to include how I retrieved my keys.

Comment: Thanks, so what was the problem in my code assuming that code works?

Answer (score 0):

Tested it with your code, slightly modified (changed `FileMode.Open` to `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, Added `File.Delete` before `File.Move` and merged `File.WriteAllText` with `File.Move`) and it works. So a) please review your code. b) If it still fails, provide more details, a single codeblock with every function and a Main-method that calls your functions to reproduce your failure...

```
    static AesCryptoServiceProvider generateAES()
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider a = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        a.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        a.BlockSize = 128;
        a.KeySize = 128;
        a.GenerateIV();
        a.GenerateKey();
        return a;
    }
    static void encryptAES(byte[] filesBytes, string filePath, AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
    {
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform crypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csStream.Write(filesBytes, 0, filesBytes.Length);
                }
                try {
                    File.Delete(filePath + ".encrypted");
                    File.Move(filePath, filePath + ".encrypted");
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                }

            }
        }
    }
    static void decryptAES(/*byte[] buffer,*/string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            AES.Key = key;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            AES.KeySize = 128;
            AES.IV = IV;

            using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform crypt = AES.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream))
                        {
                            //breaks here                      
                            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            File.WriteAllText(filePath.Replace(".encrypted", ""), data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Ill test it soon. Also I am getting the bytes to encrypt by File.ReadAllBytes(file); if that matters.

Comment: I have used `File.ReadAllBytes` for my testcase too

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This error was really annoying me and I still don't see what I did wrong but your code works thank you!

Comment: @Foxygma Then please accept and/or vote up my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I can read all bytes instead of text so that I can safely encrypt and decrypt pictures and other files as well? Like memory stream?

Comment: Instead of `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`? Yes, you could use `CryptoStream.Read(byte[], int, int)` and loop the stream until no more bytes are availiable. Or you could try replacing the hole StreamReader-using-block with this (not tested) using(var fout = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) { crStream.CopyTo(fout); }